# Spark CSV GZip to Parquet?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, gzip, parquet

I am using Spark 2.3.1 PySpark (AWS EMR)

I am getting memory errors:

Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

I have input of 160 files, each file approx 350-400 MBytes, each file is a CSV Gzip format.

To read the csv.gz files (with wildcard) and I use this Pyspark

```
dfgz = spark.read.load("s3://mybucket/yyyymm=201708/datafile_*.csv.gz",
    format="csv", sep="^", inferSchema="false", header="false", multiLine="true", quote="^", nullValue="~", schema="id string,...."))
```

To save the data frame I use this (PySpark)

```
(dfgz
.write
.partitionBy("yyyymm")
.mode("overwrite") 
.format("parquet")
.option("path", "s3://mybucket/mytable_parquet")
.saveAsTable("data_test.mytable")
)
```

One line of code to save all 160 files.

I tried this with 1 file and it works fine.

Total size for all 160 files (csv.gzip) is about 64 GBytes.

Each file as a pure CSV, when Unzipped is approx 3.5 GBytes. I am assuming Spark may unzip each file in RAM and then convert it to Parquet in RAM ??

I want to convert each csv.gzip file to Parquet format i.e. I want 160 Parquet files as output (ideally).

The task runs for a while and it seems to create 1 Parquet file for each CSV.GZ file. After some time it always fails with Yarn memory error.

I tried various settings for executors memory and memoryOverhead and all results in no change - jobs always fails. I tried memoryOverhead of up to 1-8 GB and executormemory of 8G.

Apart from manually breaking up input 160 files workload into many small workloads what else can I do? 
Do I need a Spark cluster with a total RAM capacity of much greater than 64 GB?
I use 4 slave nodes, each has 8 CPU and 16 GB per node (slaves), plus one master of 4 CPU and 8 GB of RAM.

This is (with overhead) less than 64 GB of input gzip csv files I am trying to process but the files are evenly sized of 350-400 MBytes so I dont understand why Spark is throwing memory errors given it can easily process these 1 file at a time per executor, discard it and move on to next file. It does not appear to work this way. I feel it is trying to load all input csv.gzip files into memory but I have no way of knowing it (I am still new to Spark 2.3.1).

Late Update: I managed to get it to work with following memory config:

4 slave nodes, each 8 CPU and 16 GB of RAM
1 master node, 4 CPU and 8 GB of RAM:

```
spark   maximizeResourceAllocation  false
spark-defaults  spark.driver.memoryOverhead 1g
spark-defaults  spark.executor.memoryOverhead   2g
spark-defaults  spark.executor.instances    8
spark-defaults  spark.executor.cores    3
spark-defaults  spark.default.parallelism   48
spark-defaults  spark.driver.memory 6g
spark-defaults  spark.executor.memory   6g
```

Needless to say - I cannot explain why this config worked! 
Also this took 2 hours+ to process 64 GB of gzip data which seems slow even for a small 4+1 node cluster with total of 32+4 CPU and 64+8 GB of RAM. Perhaps S3 was the bottleneck....
FWIW I just did not expect to micro-manage a database cluster for memory, disk I/O or CPU allocation.

Update 2:

I just ran another load on same cluster with same config, a smaller load of 129 files of same sizes and this load failed with same Yarn memory errors. 
I am very disappointed with Spark 2.3.1 memory management.

Thank you for any guidance

Comment: GZipped files are not splittable, hence 1 GZip => 1 partition => 1 Parquet _(unless you require a repartition)_

Comment: Look at "Spark configuration" web page, under `spark.rdd.compress`

Comment: AFAIK requiring `spark.executor.cores=3` means that Spark will run 3 tasks in parallel in each container, hence each task will have just ~1/3 of executor memory for itself. Less cores mean less throughput but lower memory pressure.

Comment: thanks, I will try your suggestions. Question: can I use "spark.executor.cores=3" from PySpark when I create a Spark session (i.e. dynamically at run time) or do I need to specify this when I create Spark cluster?

Comment: That's a session parameter. But of course the "cluster" _(Spark standalone, Mesos, YARN, K8s...)_ must have enough resources to allocate containers for the session...

Comment: thank you! If spark.read.load() reads (say) 100 files each gzip type and if I have 4 node cluster with 1 executor per node, will it process 4 gzip files concurrently, given gzip is not splittable? Or will it just use 1 executor and all others will remain idle?

Comment: It's more about _tasks_ running in parallel. 4 executors with 3 VCores each could, in theory, handle 12 tasks i.e. start reading 12 files. But you should be able to check the actual execution details by yourself, with Spark HistoryServer.

Comment: thank you! So if I make each gzip file small, perhaps 100Mbytes zipped, 1GB un-zipped then I can get multiple tasks concurrently running even though gzip files are not5 splittable? Or should I generate lzo files (also small 100MB each)?

Comment: 100 MB is likely too small to split anyway! Stop musing about theoretical possibilities and experiment the damn thing. You know the saying about "premature optimization"...